# KDE or upgrade?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, kde

I want to upgrade my home desktop to Narwal and switch from Gnome to KDE. What should I do first?

- If I switch to KDE first, I will have
  to install old KDE, then upgrade it
  to newer, and KDE is known not to
  like it.
- If I upgrade first, I will
  get all this Gnome3 and Unity stuff,
  which I need not and don't want.

Comment: no, you won't get any GNOME 3 stuff it's still GNOME 2 , you would only get Unity stuff. Which you can uninstall anyway and keep the classic desktop, so you can get KDE 4.6 switch to KDE and remove GNOME altogether

Comment: Why not keep your /home and do a clean install of Kubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ubuntu, KDE should upgrade cleanly.  If you really want not to do that, you could pare down your system, upgrade, and then install KDE, with aptitude, as follows (yes, this may be possible with apt, but I don't know how):

```
for pkg in $(aptitude search ~i | grep -v "i A" | cut -d\  -f4); do
    echo "-- markauto $pkg --"
    sudo aptitude markauto $pkg
done
```

This will prompt you several times to confirm whether sets of stuff ought be removed.  Take care not to agree to remove any cluster that includes either aptitude or ubuntu-standard.

Now, confirm you really want some packages, just to make sure things keep working, with:

```
sudo aptitude install ubuntu-standard aptitude
```

Next, clean up any leftover configuration files with:

```
sudo aptitude purge ~c
```

Now, upgrade the system to the new release:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Finally, install the packages you want from the new release

```
sudo aptitude install kubuntu-desktop^
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd recommend a nice, clean install of the Kubuntu/KDE Desktop Environment if that's what you really want. Just back up your /home folder and put it into the Kubuntu /home folder when you complete the install.

Comment: If you have /home on a different partition anyway, this works very good.